# Interpretation of parameters in loglog-regression with scaled variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interpretation, logarithm, feature-scaling

Consider e.g the model $y = e^{\text{trend} + \text{seasonality}} \cdot \prod_{k \in \text{channels}} x_k^{b_k}$

where $i$ constrained $0 < b_k < 1$ (to capture diminishing marginal returns)

Which we can linearize into $$\ln(y) = \text{trend} + \text{seasonality} + \sum_{k \, \in \, \text{channels}} b_k \ln(x_k)$$

s.t $0 < b_k < 1 $...

suppose that $\text{trend}$ is modelled by a linear trend: $\lambda t^k$ and $\text{seasonality}$ by dummies per weekday(assume daily data), $6$ in total.

We assume $b_k \sim \operatorname{Beta}(1, 1) \forall k$ and $\lambda, k, \text{dummies}$ priors all normally distributed $N(0, 1)$

We want to deal with different datasets with different scales but keep the somewhat vague priors. Thus we need to scale our input data.

We do so by maxscaling and add a constant $1$ do deal with zero values: $x_{k, \text{scaled}} = \frac{x_k}{x_{\max}} + 1$.

We do the same procedure for our dependent variables: $y_{t, \text{scaled}} = \frac{y_t}{y_{\max}} + 1$

---

How would i interpret the estimates in this scenario?

---

the bayesian aspect is not really important, it is just to showcase why the scenario might be important. What i want to get at is how the scaling of our independent and dependent variables affect our estimates in terms of interpretation.